# base64 decoding files of length greater than 8192?

Tags: c, openssl, base64

Whenever I try to base64 decode files (using OpenSSL's `BIO_f_base64()`) larger than 8192, I always seem to get some wrong value.

What is with this magic number 8192? Any help to educate me is greatly appreciated!

UPDATED:

Here is part of my code:

```
int dgst(char *alg)
 {
 EVP_MD_CTX ctx;
 const EVP_MD *md;
 unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
 unsigned int md_len, i;
 char *toB64val = NULL;
 char *data = NULL;

 OpenSSL_add_all_digests();

 md = EVP_get_digestbyname(alg);

 if(!md) {
        printf("Unknown message digest %s\n", alg);
        exit(1);
 }

 data = readFileBuffer("file_out");
 printf("strlen(data) %d\n", strlen(data));
 EVP_MD_CTX_init(&ctx);
 EVP_DigestInit_ex(&ctx, md, NULL);
 EVP_DigestUpdate(&ctx, data, strlen(data));

 EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&ctx, md_value, &md_len); //retrieve digest from ctx unto md_value and #bytes written is copied into   md_len
 EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
 unsigned char *copy = malloc(md_len);
 memcpy(copy, md_value, md_len);
 char *buff = encbase64(copy, md_len);

 printf("Digest is:%s\n ", buff);

 free(buff);
 free(toB64val);
 free(data);
 return 0;
 }


char *readFileBuffer(char *name)
{
    FILE *file;
    char *buffer = NULL;
    unsigned long fileLen;
    //Open file
    file = fopen(name, "rb");
    if (!file)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s", name);
        return;
    }
    //Get file length
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileLen=ftell(file);
    printf("file length  = %ld\n", fileLen);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    //printf("Allocate memory\n");
    buffer=(char *)malloc(fileLen+1);
    printf("length of write buffer = %d\n", strlen(buffer));
    if (!buffer)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");

    }

    long int n = fread(buffer,1, fileLen,file);
    buffer[n] = '\0';
    printf("Read no. of bytes = %ld into buffer \n", n);
    printf("len of buffer  %d  \n", strlen(buffer));
    if (!buffer)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");
        fclose(file);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return buffer;

}

char *encbase64( char *input, int length)
{
BIO *bmem, *b64;
BUF_MEM *bptr;

b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
//BIO_set_flags(b64,BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
bmem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
b64 = BIO_push(b64, bmem);

BIO_write(b64, input, length);
BIO_flush(b64);
BIO_get_mem_ptr(b64, &bptr);


char *buff = (char *)malloc(bptr->length);
memcpy(buff, bptr->data, bptr->length-1);
buff[bptr->length-1] = 0;


BIO_free_all(b64);

return buff;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE`?

Comment: what is the header file for Openssl_add_all_digests() .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't seem to have any problems with 8k boundaries. could you show us soucecode how you call it?

update:

```
int dgst(char *alg)
 {
 EVP_MD_CTX ctx;
 const EVP_MD *md;
 unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
 unsigned int md_len, i;
 char *toB64val = NULL;
 char *data = NULL;

 OpenSSL_add_all_digests();

 md = EVP_get_digestbyname(alg);

 if(!md) {
        printf("Unknown message digest %s\n", alg);
        exit(1);
 }

 data = readFileBuffer("file_out");
 //printf("strlen(data) %d\n", strlen(data)); <- don't use strlen on binary data
 EVP_MD_CTX_init(&ctx);
 EVP_DigestInit_ex(&ctx, md, NULL);
 EVP_DigestUpdate(&ctx, data, strlen(data));

 EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&ctx, md_value, &md_len); //retrieve digest from ctx unto md_value and #bytes written is copied into   md_len
 EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
 unsigned char *copy = malloc(md_len);
 memcpy(copy, md_value, md_len);
 char *buff = encbase64(copy, md_len);

 printf("Digest is:%s\n ", buff);

 free(buff);
 free(toB64val);
 free(data);
 return 0;
 }


char *readFileBuffer(char *name)
{
    FILE *file;
    char *buffer = NULL;
    unsigned long fileLen;
    //Open file
    file = fopen(name, "rb");
    if (!file)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s", name);
        return;
    }
    //Get file length
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileLen=ftell(file);
    printf("file length  = %ld\n", fileLen);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    //printf("Allocate memory\n");
    buffer=(char *)malloc(fileLen/*+1*/); // <- not a string - no need to +1
    //printf("length of write buffer = %d\n", strlen(buffer)); <- again strlen on binary data (you just allocated it, so it contains random bytes)
    if (!buffer)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");

    }

    long int n = fread(buffer,1, fileLen,file);
    //buffer[n] = '\0';                  // not a string - no need to end it
    printf("Read no. of bytes = %ld into buffer \n", n);
    //printf("len of buffer  %d  \n", strlen(buffer));  <- buffer length is in 'n'
    if (!buffer)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");
        fclose(file);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return buffer;

}

char *encbase64( char *input, int length)
{
BIO *bmem, *b64;
BUF_MEM *bptr;

b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
//BIO_set_flags(b64,BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
bmem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
b64 = BIO_push(b64, bmem);

BIO_write(b64, input, length);
BIO_flush(b64);
BIO_get_mem_ptr(b64, &bptr);


char *buff = (char *)malloc(bptr->length);
memcpy(buff, bptr->data, bptr->length/*-1*/); // removed '+1'
//buff[bptr->length-1] = 0;       // not a string


BIO_free_all(b64);

return buff;
}
```

Comment: Hello fazo, I have updated my post with the code. Please take a look

Comment: then you need to adjust your code, because you are using strlen on binary data (when you call EVP_DigestUpdate for example)

Comment: I guess in the above code, what I've missed is the base64 decoding part. So the binary files am reading are the ones that are  to be digested with SHA1. The important part is  printf("len of buffer  %d  \n", strlen(buffer)); in readFileBuffer returns one digit values while 'n' in the prev line returns the exact file length which means the fread does work :(

Comment: Thanks for the points. I was re-using the readFileBuffer function for reading base64 encoded files as well as binary files-That is why you see the strlen used. However I didnt realize this would fail for binary files. Is there any way to use a generic file reading function(my code is getting way too big)..thanks